# Visitor Pattern Item Tracker

Tags: c#, .net, visitor-pattern

In an implementation of the visitor pattern with interfaces as follow (feel free to tell me if you think the interfaces themselves are wrong), who should be responsible for tracking a list of all the items visited? The visitor or the visitable? Specifically, the tracker must also be responsible for making sure the same item isn't visited twice (if the graph I'm visiting contains circular references).

```
/// <summary>
/// Defines a type that may accept visitors.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
public interface IVisitable<T>
{
    // Methods
    void Accept(T instance, IVisitor<T> visitor);
}

/// <summary>
/// Defines a type that visits objects.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
public interface IVisitor<T>
{
    // Methods
    void Visit(IVisitable<T> visitable);

    // Properties
    bool HasCompleted { get; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The visitor should keep track of all items that it have visited. The visitor is always aware of what it visits, compared to the `IVisitable` who only knows that it can be visited.

Any other solution would increase the coupling.

As your interfaces, I would change them so that they look like this:

```
public interface IVisitable<T>
{
    void Accept(IVisitor<T> visitor);
}

public interface IVisitor<T>
{
    bool Visit(T item);
}
```

This means that the visitor should keep a list of visited items if it may not process the same item more than once:

```
public class MyVisitor : IVisitor<TheItem>
{
    private List<TheItem> _visitedItems = new List<TheItem>();

    public bool Visit(TheItem item)
    {
         if (_visitedItems.Contains(item)) return true;
         _visitedItems.Add(item);

         //process here. Return false when iteration should be stopped.
    }
}

public class MyItems : IVisitable<TheItem>
{

     public void Accept(IVisitor<TheItem> visitor)
     {
         foreach (var item in items)
         {
             if (!visitor.Visit(item))
                 break;
         }
     }
}
```

**Update 2**

`IEnumerable` (iterators) is really an evolution of the visitor pattern. The difference is that you move the loop from inside the visited class to outside.

**Update 3**

You can create a list: `List<MyItem> items = new List<MyItem>();` and iterate it using the `foreach` statement (which uses the `IEnumerable<T>` interface):

```
foreach (var item in items)
{
    //do anything here. use `break` to exit loop.
}
```

That's the same thing as:

```
var enumerator = items.GetEnumerator();
while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    Console.WriteLine("The item: " + enumerator.Current);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that given the interfaces above. Should IVisitor has a Visit(T instance) method, not Visit(IVisitable<T> visitable)? Or should it take both an instance and a visitable?

Comment: But how can the visitor know the iteration should be stopped if only the visitable contains the list of items? I want to visit the entire graph until all nodes are visited.

Comment: then it should just keep returning true until it's not called anymore.

Comment: Right, but who should be responsible for making sure the same node isn't visited twice? The visitable? Or should I just implement IEnumerable? Sounds more straightforward

Comment: It's always the one visiting (as in my example) that should keep track of visited items. If this is not a school assignment I would go for `IEnumerator` instead of implementing visitor pattern. There are several examples on the net.

Comment: .NET framework is huge and it can be hard to find the correct classes/interfaces sometimes. Been there, done that.